# Unable to get the Cardview, E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error , how to add adapter to recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm using the android studio to build an application. I'm getting "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" when running the app. 
Since I'm new to android studio development, unable to figure out the problem. I tried several solutions online, but it didn't work for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private List <Upload> uploads;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    uploads = new ArrayList<>();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("upload");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Upload upload = postsnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
            uploads.add(upload);

            }
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),uploads);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
```

**Adapter**
This is my adapter code, sometime it will be wrong or I had a mistake check these two and please give me an idea to correct this problem.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private Context mContext;
private List <Upload> uploads;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.uploads = uploads;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_item,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final  Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.tv_book_title.setText(upload.getName());

    Glide.with(mContext).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imd_book_thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uploads.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_book_title;
    ImageView imd_book_thumbnail;
    CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_book_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id);
        imd_book_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_img_id);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add what steps you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I tried moved positions in my adapter code but it's not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the adapter in `onCreate` method, right now you're doing it in a listener. My guess is you just need to move the `recylerView.setAdapter(adapter)` in `onCreate` and just set the datas and `notifyDataSetChanged` in your `listener`

It should look like this:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    uploads = new ArrayList<>();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("upload");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postsnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploads.add(upload);
            }
            adapter.setList(uploads);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> uploads;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.uploads = uploads;
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void setList(List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_item,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final  Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.tv_book_title.setText(upload.getName());

    Glide.with(mContext).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imd_book_thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uploads == null ? 0 : uploads.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_book_title;
    ImageView imd_book_thumbnail;
    CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_book_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id);
        imd_book_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_img_id);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you did?

Comment: I removed ecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)  at end of create method, please correct me if I wrong

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how it should look like

Comment: That's because you need to create the method in your adapter, could you edit your original post and add your adapter. That method will set the new data to your adapter

Comment: Look at my updated code, and tell us what is the error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: can you edit your main post and add your adapter to it ?

Comment: I've add my code, as you see, you need to create a new constructor with context only, and create a new public method to set the data, also i slightly change the `getItemCount()`

Comment: W/SyncTree: Listen at /upload failed: DatabaseError: Permission what is this is in the run tab but not highlight as error

Comment: yep that's not something related to recyclerview, right now you're recyclerview is working

Comment: sure no problem :)

Comment: The problem is the same as here. cardview is no visible